# Using python and ffmpeg to split .mp4 video into chunks of few seconds

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I would like to split videos into small chunks of two seconds while maintaining good quality and running fast.

I've tried various techniques on StackOverflow such as

- [Using Python script to cut long videos into chunks in FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884159/using-python-script-to-cut-long-videos-into-chunks-in-ffmpeg)
- [Cut .mp4 in pieces Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334379/cut-mp4-in-pieces-python)
- [python library for splitting video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580576/python-library-for-splitting-video)
- [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)
- ...

But the result does not satisfy me. Some are too slow, and some do not give the short-length chunk.